# how to get total days of a specific month in date_select in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In view code i have:

{:controller=>'offers',:action=>'create'})do |f| %>

```
<%= f.date_select :startDate_get ,start_year=>2014,:end_year=>2020,:order=>[:month,:day,:year],:use_short_month=>true %>

<%= f.date_select :endDate_get ,start_year=>2014,:end_year=>2020,:order=>[:month,:day,:year],:use_short_month=>true %>
```

I am new in rails.

The problem with this **date_select** is that when i select any month i want to see its days.Like, when i select February month i want to see only `28 days of 2014 year`.
Now its showing all **31** days.

Thus, i want to validate for all days with month.

Comment: you need to write some jquery to get such functionality

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**View:**

```
$('#start_date_2i').change(function(){
        var month = $(this).val()
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: '/get_date',
          data: {month: month},
          success: function(data){
            $('#start_date_3i option').length = data
          }
        })
      })
```

**Controller:**

```
 def get_date
    @month = params[:month]
        @date = Time.days_in_month(@month)
        return @date
  end
```

**Routes:**

```
get '/get_date'=> 'controller#get_date'
```

Comment: I have edited my code above.What is option in the last line of the jquery code?Nothing is happening when i am trying this code.